# Setting a new mask grabcut JAVA

Tags: java, opencv, mask

How should I apply the grabcut but instead using INIT_WITH_RECT, use INTI_WITH_MASK? So far what I got is this, probably with Images you can see my real problem:

First you can select the part you want as your ROI in this case the part selected is mark with a gray rectangle:

[image]
Applying grabcut with INIT_WITH_RECT  the algorithm show this:

[image]

The code that I use in  this first grabcut operation is:

```
    Rect selection = new Rect(x1,y1,x2,y2);
    Mat mask = new Mat();;
    Mat cmp = new Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(3));
    Mat bkground; 
    Mat frground;
    Mat foreground;//keep the result of the grabcut

   Imgproc.grabCut(imagen, mask,selection, bkground,
   frground,5,Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT);
   Core.compare(mask, cmp,cmp, Core.CMP_EQ);
   foreground = newMat(imagen.size(),CvType.CV_8UC3,newScalar(0,0,0));
   imagen.copyTo(foreground,mask);
```

As you can see the grabcut select a part that is not wanted so Im trying to enhance the selection with doing some touchups in the parts you want as foreground and as a background, in this example foreground is mark with blue and background with red as below:

[image]

Here comes the problem, how to apply again the grabcut algorithm but now indicating that the blue lines are foreground and the red lines are background? I have read about it and saw the Python examples, but in Python the use of arrays is far different from Java.

What I know and correct me if I'm wrong, I have to modify the mask and reapply the grabcut algorithm, I have tried this, in the result image of the grabcut (that in this example the variable name is "foreground") I found the color I marked as red or blue and change the values in the mask image, with the corresponding values for foreground that is 1 and for background that is 0:

```
paintit = bufferedtoMat(foreground);
totalbytes = (int) (paintit.total() * paintit.elemSize());
byte buffer[] = new byte [totalbytes];
                    /**********************************************************/
 int totalbytesMask = (int) (mask.total() * mask.elemSize());
 byte maskBuffer[] = new byte[totalbytesMask];
 Mat newMask = new Mat(mask.height(),mask.width(),CvType.CV_8UC1);
                    /*********************************************************/


  paintit.get(0,0,buffer);
  mask.get(0, 0,maskBuffer);

  for(i = 0; i < totalbytes; i = i+3)
  {
       for(int j = i ; j < i+3; j++)
       {
          tmpBlue[h] =(buffer[j] & 255);
          tmpRed[h] = (buffer [j] & 255);
          h++;
       }

                       h = 0;

                       for(int k = 0; k < blue.length; k++)
                       {

                           if(tmpBlue[k] == blue[k])
                           {

                               flagBlue++;
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               flagBlue = 0;
                           }


                           if(tmpRed[k] == red[k])
                           {

                               flagRed++;


                           }
                           else
                           {
                               flagRed = 0;

                           }


                       }
                       if(flagBlue == blue.length)
                       {

                           for(int l = i; l < blue.length;l++)
                           {

                               maskBuffer[l] = azul;
                               buffer[l] = azul;
                           }

                           System.out.println("Hay un azul...");
                           flagBlue = 0;

                       }
                       if(flagRed == red.length)
                       {

                           for(int m = i; m < red.length;m++)
                           {

                               maskBuffer[m] = rojo;
                               buffer[m] = rojo;

                           }


                           System.out.println("Hay un rojo...");
                           flagRed= 0;


                       }





                   }

                   paintit.put(0,0,buffer);
                   mask.put(0,0,maskBuffer);
```

After all this operation and with the mask changed I tried to apply the grabcut operation again:

```
Imgproc.grabCut(source,mask,rectangle,background,forground,5,Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK);
```

But I got this error:

```
Assertion failed (!bgdSamples.empty() && !fgdSamples.empty()) in initGMMs
```

I have checked that this matrix are not zero or they exist and the results are:

```
Mask:Mat [ 494*954*CV_8UC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x1d140a00, dataAddr=0x1d211f20 ]
Background:Mat [ 1*65*CV_64FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x1d1404c0, dataAddr=0x390b00 ]
ForegroundMat [ 1*65*CV_64FC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x1d140450, dataAddr=0x3908d0 ]
Rectangle{252, 235, 345x342}
```

So the problem is how to set the new mask?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you resolve?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry for the late response, what I did was to look for the foreground and background pixels manually and reapply the mask of the grabcut, and it actually worked. It was kind of hardcoding the result of the grabcut.

Answer (score 0):

The error happens when either the background or foreground has no value.

While setting the values, you have either made all the pixel values to be Foreground i.e 1 or 3, Or you have made all pixel values as background i.e 0 or 2.

Check the pixel values to know about the error.